# virtualbox black screen of death

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, linux-mint

Trying to run virtualbox on a windows 10 (2004) machine as host with linux-mint as vm.  When we start up the vm we get the install linux screen and then after 10 seconds a black screen.  Hyper-v and 3d acceleration are both off. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off hyper-v is not enough.  A number of other window 10 features if checked will turn on hyper-v even if it isn't checked. Once those are unchecked you are good to go.  All of the following need to be disabled:

```
Application Guard
Credential Guard (see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/downloa ... x?id=53337)
Device Guard (see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/downloa ... x?id=53337)
<any> * Guard
Containers
Hyper-V
Virtual Machine Platform
Windows Hypervisor Platform
Windows Sandbox
Windows Server Containers
Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) (WSL1 does not enable Hyper-V)
```